# using datatables to the data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

The following is my try to find the data attribute of the datatbales happening on sever side, but i am not getting it

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).find('data-source');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.find('data-source'));
  });
```

the html lookalike of this piece in the console is like this

https://prnt.sc/wntp08

i am trying to get the value but the code i am using is not right

Comment: What is the structure of your datatable?

Comment: `table` is undefined. That looks like the inspector to me, not the console. `.find('[data-source]')` is how you get an Element by an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of your code

**method 1:**

you can use by **class** dropdown

```
 console.log($(this).find('.dropdown').data('source'));
```

**method 2:**

you can use by **element** div

```
 console.log($(this).find('div').data('source'));
```